# Able to plot 2 graphs in a row but not 3. get ValueError: values must be a 1D array

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the dataframe:

```
Data for last 8 months

                        date     close  volume  change%      obv  compare   close_trend
6  2022-06-30 00:00:00+05:30  18760.40  358433     5.52  1358338     True  18482.242046
7  2022-07-31 00:00:00+05:30  20015.10  252637     6.27  1610975     True  18905.447351
8  2022-08-31 00:00:00+05:30  18739.75  317107    -6.81  1293868    False  19328.826505
9  2022-09-30 00:00:00+05:30  19139.15  561137     2.09  1855005     True  19753.246889
10 2022-10-31 00:00:00+05:30  19246.95  243999     0.56  2099004     True  20179.207712
11 2022-11-30 00:00:00+05:30  20237.80  311138     4.90  2410142     True  20606.824373
12 2022-12-31 00:00:00+05:30  21367.20  386070     5.29  2796212     True  21035.629608
13 2023-01-31 00:00:00+05:30  22250.00  101527     3.97  2897739     True  21464.925515
```

I am able to plot 2 graphs in a row using matplotlib in **jupyter notebook**.

```
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
            plt.subplot(1,2,1)
            plt.plot(df['date'], df['close'], color='red', figure=fig)
            plt.subplot(1,2,2)
            plt.plot(df[['close','close_trend']],figure=fig)
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

But when I try to plot 3 graphs like this, I get **`ValueError: values must be a 1D array`**

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
    plt.subplot(1,3,1)
    plt.plot(df['date'], df['close'], color='red', figure=fig)
    plt.subplot(1,3,2)
    plt.plot(df[['close','close_trend']],figure=fig)
    plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    plt.plot(df.index, df['obv'],color='blue', figure=fig)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

How do I get 3 plots in a row?

Comment: It worked once I changed `plt.plot(1,3,3)` to `plt.subplot(1,3,3)`... you used `plot` instead of `subplot`

Comment: changed it but no luck

Comment: Are you using recent matplotlib and pandas versions?  Are you sure the index isn't a multi-index?  Did you try only plotting `plt.plot(df.index, df['obv'])` without anything else (not even creating subplots)?